# Как внести изменения в файл находящийся в контейнере DOCKER из локального терминала

Tags: linux, docker

По типу: `ssh user@host echo 123 >> 1.txt` только в докере. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker exec [container] sh -c 'echo 123 >> 1.txt'
```